# When should setReorderingAllowed() be called on a FragmentTransaction?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

At [this part](https://youtu.be/eUG3VWnXFtg?t=8m16s) of a talk given at Google I/O 2017, the speaker introduces a new API for `setReorderingAllowed()` than can be called on a `FragmentTransaction`.

The speaker explains:

> It allows all the execution to happen all at once without changing
>   your fragment state and then at the very end we bring up all the
>   fragments that need to be brought up and tear down all the fragments
>   that need to be torn down…so we can optimize this for you.

And shows the following code sample:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, fragment1)
    .addToBackStack("state1")
    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
    .commit();

fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, fragment2)
    .addToBackStack("state2")
    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
    .commit();
```

Wouldn't committing the `FragmentTransaction`s separately negate any optimization that `.setReorderingAllowed(true)` gives you because they are occurring separately?

Since this is a newly announced API it looks like there is no documentation currently available.

Comment: The method `setAllowOptimization` was deprecated in API level 26.0.0-beta2 and has been renamed to `setReorderingAllowed(boolean)`.

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setReorderingAllowed(boolean)) is also available now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the method they mention already exists since support library 25.1.0 but is currently called `setAllowOptimization(true)`. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setAllowOptimization(boolean)) clearly states "optimizing operations within and across transactions" so it will optimize distinct transactions.

Comment: SEE ABOVE COMMENT: "The method setAllowOptimization was deprecated in API level 26.0.0-beta2 and has been renamed to setReorderingAllowed(boolean). Documentation is also available now."

Comment: To be clear: I never said anyone should use `setAllowOptimization()`. I clearly stated it was the **old name** of the same method and referred to the documentation of it, which answers the question.